# I can't drive can I get a drivers license in USA just to be used as an ID

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, identity-cards

I will be studying in the US as an international student soon, and I don't have any proper training to be able to drive a vehicle.

I know that the drivers license does comes in handy a lot in the US as an identification document/card so my question is: Can I get a drivers license just to use it as an identification card instead of carrying my passport everywhere with me?

Or maybe a special version of the drivers license, one that says that I can't or not allowed to drive?

Comment: Many states call this a "non-driver ID"

Comment: I'm looking at "Driver License" and an "Identification Card" from the same state.  The license has a few extra lines with the class and restrictions and more detail on these on the back.  On a quick glance you could mistake the two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did an exchange year in Oklahoma (I am British) and was able to get a state ID without having any utility bills. I can't remember exactly what identification I did have to take (possibly a letter from the university with my Oklahoma address on it). I imagine it varies from state to state, so I would ask the university. They should know :)

Comment: what do you mean by an OK address?

Comment: @user9619 *OK* is the two-letter abbreviation for the state of Oklahoma. OK?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - it has been edited now.

Comment: Something else to add - I think I was required to get a state ID as I was living there for a certain length of time. I really can't remember exactly as it was 5 years ago now, but I do remember the whole group of us getting them (9 of us went together). 
I also did a lot of driving while I was there, and was able to do this just using my British driving license.

Comment: FWIW, in every state I am aware of, the Department/Registry/whatever of Motor Vehicles is also the place to get a non-driver ID, since they have the infrastructure in place anyway.

Comment: @emmalgale There's no general requirement for a government issued photo ID.  There're enough things you either can't do or which are significantly more annoying to do without one that I've never understood why people wouldn't get one; but enough people don't that any attempt to add a requirement to have one for a govt function turns into a political brawl.

Comment: You are probably right. We may have just all got them because it meant we didn't need to carry around our passports every day for 10 months. As I said, it was 5 years ago now, so I can't remember exactly why we got one. I kept mine as a souvenir!

Comment: @Casey, in Oklahoma and Texas, it's DPS that gives out IDs/licences.  And, no, it doesn't stand for Dorozhno-Patrul'naya Sluzhba, that one's in Russia (ДПС).

Answer (score 9):

You can only get a state ID. They will not give you a drivers license if you cant drive or haven''t taken their driving exam.  A state ID can be given to anyone who lives in the state and have bills under their name.

Answer (score 1):

Nope... I am not sure if there is any 'simple version' of a driver's license. Never heard of it. I dont think there is anything like it.

probably you are referring to a state ID. Once you go to US, get electricity, gas connections on your name. You can use this to get a state ID. I guess in some states, you can also get one based on your student ID.

Answer (score 1):

In New York there is a card called an "Identification Card." These cards are for people who don't have a license, and for people who didn't even take the permit test. I had a friend in college who had one of these things to get into bars.

Link for more information: [ID Cards in NY](http://dmv.ny.gov/id-card/bget-non-driver-id-card-ndid)